# Scala map isDefinedAt() vs contains() method

Tags: scala, dictionary

Below is my HashMap:

```
val params1 = collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Any]()

params1 += "forCourseId" -> "2"

println(params1.isDefinedAt("forCourseId"))

println(params1.contains("forCourseId"))
```

What is difference between `isDefinedAt()` & `contains()` method?

I need to check whether key is present or not
main concern is , it will not throw null pointer exception.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check the Scala source code.  In `MapLike.scala` you'll see that `isDefinedAt` is actually just calling `contains`, meaning that they are truly identical:

```
def isDefinedAt(key: A) = contains(key)
```

The only real difference is that `contains` is specific to the `Map` interface (specifically it's declared on `GenMapLike`), while `isDefinedAt` is found on all `PartialFunction` classes.

```
val m: Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)
val pf: PartialFunction[Int,Int] = { case 1 => 1 }

m.isDefinedAt(1)  // ok
m.contains(1)     // ok
pf.isDefinedAt(1) // ok
pf.contains(1)    // doesn't compile
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Scala Doc `isDefinedAt` is equivalent to `contains`.

> This method, which implements an abstract method of trait PartialFunction, is equivalent to contains.

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.mutable.HashMap